# How to search Dictionary with Instance as Key

Tags: c#, dictionary

Here's my dictionary declaration:

```
public IDictionary<MYType<IMyType>, IList<MYType<IMyType>>> SomeList {
    get;
    set;
}
```

`MYType<T>` has the properties `MyTypeId` and `MyTypeParentId`.

1. If I want to search the key on `MyTypeParentId`, is this possible?
2. Or should I just declare `MyTypeParentId` as `int` and not make my key a `MYType<T>`?

I sort of want the key to be a type of `MyType<IMyType>` because it's got other useful properties in that instance.

So having that instance available as the key, I thought would allow me to key off of several different properties that exist within `MYType<T>` that I could match on ...

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of a Dictionary is a fast search by the *hash code* of a key (of any type), not a property (or properties) of the key. Of course, you can search against the properties of the Key type through the `Keys` collection, but it won't be a *fast* search.

If you want to search by `MyTypeParentId`, make a Dictionary with int key, and use `MyTypeParentId` as the key.

Comment: so you're saying it'll slow down the search if I key by type instead of Id?  I don't even see how I'd search on this even so it being a type.

Comment: Why couldn't I go MyType.ParentId to key off of since MyType has ParentId as a property of MyType?

Comment: IList<MyType> children;

            if (MyDictionary.TryGetValue(myType.ParentId, out children)) but that doesn't work in terms of syntax is what I was trying to do.  I see the value of having a type instead of an id for the key initially again because I figured I could search on several types of ints via the properties of MyType key.  Example lets say MyType has MyType.ColorId I figured ok I should be able to be flexible here and search on any of the properties of MyType since MyType is the key

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: "so you're saying it'll slow down the search if I key by type instead of Id" - no, I'm saying, that dictionary isn't a database. If you want to search by instances of `MYType`, use them as keys (and make `Dictionary<MYType, Anything>`). If you want to search by `MYType.MyTypeParentId`, use parent ids as keys (and make `Dictionary<int, Anything>`).

Answer (score 0):

Only use your type as the key if you will be looking up instances of that type. If you need to look up values corresponding to an int ID, build your dictionary with int keys.

Perhaps maintaining multiple dictionaries will help you (e.g. one keyed on type ID and one keyed on patent type ID).